# html&css set a white arrow to the bottom image

Tags: html, css, image

http://judopassion.com/wordpress/

In content div there are some article object. Each article has one image. On the image I would draw an arrow on the left bottom image.
I have realized it with div contentArrow.
The problem is that all the images has got same width but different height, so I don't know how fix the contentArrow for all type of height.
Now the contentArrow is well displayed only for images 269px height.
[image]
How can I do it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#contentImageSrc` has to be a class `.contentImageSrc` because you are using it multiple times. **The Rule** you can not repeat IDs

Move `contentArrow div` inside `contentImageSrc DIV` and then write your css as -

```
.contentImageSrc{ position: relative; }
.contentArrow { position: absolute; bottom: 10px; left: 10px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the image in a div with relative position and absolutely position the arrow inside that setting the 'bottom' value to 0:

```
<div class="imageWrapper">
    <div class="contentArrow"></div>
    <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.imageWrapper{position:relative}
    .contentArrow{position:absolute; background:url(arrow.png); bottom:0; left:15px}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually accomplish all of this with just a wrapper and some clever CSS.

The following shows an example. Note that much of the CSS is just for prettiness - the actual meat of the functionality is the fact that the `IMG` tags are wrapped in `SPAN`s, and the `SPAN` tags have the following applied:

```
span.selected:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px; left: 50%; 
    margin: 0 0 0 -25px;
    height: 0; width: 0;
    border: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

By styling the `:after` element of the specific class like this - you create the white portion of the arrow. The additional styling for the `:before` element is just to create the black border around the white arrow.

You can see a working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/wRrW6/

```
<span><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" /></span>
<span class="selected"><img src="http://placekitten.com/410/410" /></span>
<span><img src="http://placekitten.com/420/420" /></span>

<style type="text/css">
img {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px; margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px; height: 200px;
}
span { display: inline-block; }
span:hover { cursor: pointer; }
span.selected { position: relative; }
span.selected > img { background: #268; }
span.selected:before, span.selected:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px; left: 50%; 
    margin: 0 0 0 -25px;
    height: 0; width: 0;
    border: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    z-index: 1;
}
span.selected:after {
    bottom: 9px; left: 50%; 
    margin: 0 0 0 -25px;
    height: 0; width: 0;
    border: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
</style>
```